# T-SQL - Insert Missing Data for Specific Period of Time

Tags: sql, t-sql, bigdata, relational-database

I am having trouble solving this problem with missing data for 4/13-4/15. See screenshot: [Daily Subscriber Counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOlFh.png)

This screenshot was produced by [Edit: Part Of] the following code:

```
SELECT  
    MIN([AsOfDate]) AS StartDate,
    MAX([AsOfDate]) AS EndDate,
    SUM([TotalCustomers]) AS TotalSubs,
    SUM([HSDCustomers]) AS HSDSubs,
    SUM([PhoneCustomers]) AS PhoneSubs,
    SUM([VideoCustomers]) AS VideoSubs
FROM 
    [vDailyCustomerCounts]
WHERE
    Sourcesystem = 'ICOMS'
    AND (Asofdate BETWEEN '4/8/2018' AND '4/18/2018')
    AND iscommercial = 0
GROUP BY 
    [AsOfDate]
ORDER BY 
    [AsOfDate] DESC
```

Essentially my issue is that I need to insert "dummy" data into the select statement. I need to create a row for 2018-04-13 through 2018-04-15 and populate it with either a general count (like 502,900) or use the previous day's count.

Ideally, I want to create something like below:

```
StartDate   End Date     TotalSubs
----------------------------------
2018-04-13  2018-04-13   502900
```

I only want to insert this dummy data if a missing day occurs in the data set. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Do those dates exist at all in your data? Or if you had a dates table you could join it.

Comment: Nope, these values do not exist at all in any table.  Basically, a job got stuck over those few days and so no data was populated into those tables until the underlying issue was fixed.  Now I need to create rows for those days and some generic values as placeholders for other calculations

Comment: Makes no sense.  If you group by [AsOfDate] then MIN([AsOfDate]) and MAX([AsOfDate]) are just [AsOfDate]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop like this to fill in your missing dates first- then add the default values and continue on with your aggregation

```
  declare @mindate datetime=(select min(Asofdate) from vDailyCustomerCounts)
  declare @maxdate datetime=(select max(Asofdate) from vDailyCustomerCounts)
  declare @date datetime=@mindate
  declare @missing table(datevalue datetime )
  while @date<@maxdate
  begin
  if @date not in (select Asofdate from vDailyCustomerCounts)
  insert @missing 
  select @date
  set @date=@date+1 
  end 


select a.datevalue, 
    b.TotalCustomers ,
    b.HSDCustomers ,
    b.PhoneCustomers,
    b.VideoCustomers 
from (select Asofdate from vDailyCustomerCounts  
union select * from @missing )a 
        left join vDailyCustomerCounts b on a.Asofdate =b.Asofdate
```

Comment: Hi Daniel.  I appreciate your help but I think it either did not work or (and) I do not have a great understanding of SQL.  The code ran but I did not notice any difference. How can I query @missing by itself to see if any values populated within it?

Comment: Sorry typo - see edited above - let me know if that works for you - this should return a list of all the dates between your min and max date - you can then join this list to your original dataset and fill in any dates missing from your original set with any data you want

Comment: Added code that will give you a new original data set to work with that will include placeholders for your missing dates - aggregate from there accordingly

Comment: holy **** that did it!  I have to be honest, I (sort of) understand how that works but never would have thought of it on my own.  Do you tutor?  I would love to get in contact with you somehow.  I feel really out of my comfort zone doing this (at the moment) and you nailed it!

Comment: Sure happy to help anytime - connect with me on linkedin

Comment: Got it - message me next time you need help

Answer (score 0):

See this web page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

You can use CASE in your SELECT statement to choose a dummy value if an undesirable value is present.